# How to change eclipse scroll bar color

Tags: eclipse, scrollbar, preferences

I'm new to programming and have seen some other threads, but I don't really know how to execute the solutions, so can someone please walk me through it all?

Comment: which os are you using?

Answer (score -3):

You can add some css codes to your Eclipse:

```
#org-eclipse-e4-ui-compatibility-editor * { background-color: #yourColor; }
```

Or you can go to `Preferences > General > Editors > Text`, then uncheck "show range indicator".

Comment: No I'm asking about the scroll bar on the right and bottom side, not the blue bar on the left of line numbers